# How to initialize the state of each item component in the component array in React?

Tags: reactjs

```
const products = [
    {
      id: 1,
      ...
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      ...
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      ...
    },
];
```

I created the ProductList component, which contains 3 Product components:

```
    class ProductList extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
       super(props)
      }

      render() {
        const productComponents = products.map((product) => (
           <Product 
                key = {'product-' + product.id}
                id = {product.id}
                ...
            />
        ));
        return ( 
              <ul className="holder-list row">
                {productComponents}
              </ul> 
        );
       }
     }

     class Product extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
       super(props)
      }
       render() {
         return(..)
       }
     }
```

How and in which component in the constructor to set a different initial state for all three products?

I want set the initial value of this.state for each Product different.

Example:

for Product with id:1 - `this.state={color: blue}`,

for Product with id:2 - `this.state={color: yellow}`,

for Product with id:3 - `this.state={color: red}`.

How can I do something like this?

Comment: don't understand what exactly the problem is ? can't you have `this.state = { products }` ?

Comment: Each `Product` is getting it's own props and can have it's own separate state exactly the way you have it. Are you asking how to change `products` array of `ProductList` from a child component? Or are you asking how to work with props in a child component in conjunction with that respective `Product`'s state?

Comment: There is [static getDerivedStateFromProps()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) that can be used in `Product`, but if you share more about what you are trying do to in `Product` with that `color`, there may very likely be a better way to calculate that and maybe provide that to `Product` from `ProductList` as a prop instead.

Comment: Look at [this](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) first, it has some great information regarding how to approach "derived state". That being said, you should probably share more about the use of `color` in `Product` to allow others to better help answer your question.

Comment: Ok, @AlexanderStaroselsky. Thank you. I will do so.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky, I just want to know how to set the initial state for each product in constructor.

Comment: Are you asking about the constructor of `ProductList` or `Product`? Do you want to update `products` array before rendering in `ProductList`, or you do mean when `Product` receives props?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky, I want change state of Product. Example by click.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179851/discussion-between-user7376346-and-alexander-staroselsky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you could approach setting state `color` for `Product`. These are both inspired from a great article [You Probably Don't Need Derived State](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#when-to-use-derived-state) which provides some great examples on how to handle "derived state".

ProductList - Create a method the returns a string color value based on your id to color requirements. This can be outside of the class definition, it doesn't/shouldn't need to be a method on class `ProductList` as it doesn't need the `this` or similar. Add an additional prop, something like `defaultColor`, that is passed to each instance of `Product`:

```
const getColor = id => {
  switch (id) {
    case 1:
      return 'blue';
    case 2:
      return 'yellow';
    case 3:
      return 'red'
    default:
      return '';
  }
};

// ...

render() {
  const productComponents = products.map((product) => (
    <Product 
      key = {'product-' + product.id}
      id = {product.id}
      defaultColor={getColor(product.id)}
      ...
    />
  ));
}
```

Product - Set initial state using the `defaultColor` prop being passed in. Using a different property would allow each `Product` component to fully control it's own color state value/changes with something like an `<input />`, but copy over the initial color value:

```
class Product extends Component {
  state = { color: this.props.defaultColor };

  // ...

  render() {
    return ({/* ... */});
  }
}
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-h8qw6w) demonstrating the functionality in action.

The other options is using [static getDerivedStateFromProps()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) in `Product`. It conditionally checks if the `id` prop has changed to avoid setting state unnecessarily and overriding `Product` local state values. We are keeping track of the previous `id` value so that it can be used in the conditional statement to see if any changes actually happened:

```
class Product extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      prevId: -1,
      color: ''
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.id !== state.prevId) {
      switch (props.id) {
        case 1:
          return { color: 'blue', prevId: props.id };
        case 2:
          return { color: 'yellow', prevId: props.id };
        case 3:
          return { color: 'red', prevId: props.id };
        default:
          return null;
      }
    }

    return null
  }

  render() {
    return ({/* ... */});
  }
}
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9k1wsr) demonstrating this functionality.

It's hard to say exactly how to approach this as it may be likely you do not need state in `Product`. That `Product` can act as a "dumb" component just receiving props and emitting value changes to a higher order component like `ProductList`.

Hopefully that helps!